# Covert mysql to postgresql query

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have an example that works perfectly in mysql but when I converts to postgresql don't works.

**Mysql Code: (index.php):**

```
<?php 
  require('includes/connection.php'); 
  include('func.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<form action="" method="post">

    <select name="drop_1" id="drop_1">

      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Category</option>

      <?php getTierOne(); ?>

    </select> 

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Mysql code(func.php):**

```
function getTierOne()
{       

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT tier_one FROM three_drops") 
or die(mysql_error());

  while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

    {
       echo '<option value="'.$tier['tier_one'].'">'.$tier['tier_one'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

**POstgreSql Code: (index.php):**

```
<?php 
  require('includes/connection.php'); 
  include('func.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<form action="" method="post">

    <select name="drop_1" id="drop_1">

      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Category</option>

      <?php getTierOne(); ?>

    </select> 

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PostgreSql code(func.php):**

```
function getTierOne()
{       

        $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT DISTINCT tier_one FROM three_drops");

      while($tier = $sth->fetch()) 

        {
           echo '<option value="'.$tier['tier_one'].'">'.$tier['tier_one'].'</option>';
        }
}
```

**Connections (Postgresql):**

```
require("constants.php");

    $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS,
    array (PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ));
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

The connection is working but I get an error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object.

Comment: Should the $dbh object be initialized somewhere because now it isn't? What do you have in connection.php? Maybe just replace $dbh->query with pg_query and $sth->fetch with pg_fetch_assoc($sth)?

Comment: I update my question with the connection. I try your suggestion but I have the same result: Call to a member function pg_query() on a non-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the $dbh global.

connection.php:

```
require("constants.php");
global $dbh;
```

func.php:

```
function getTierOne()
{
  global $dbh;
```

Comment: Don't works, I get the same problem.If I only select and echo the row outside the function works fine, but inside the select box nothing happens.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The global $dbh; needs to be inside the function. Edited.